# « J'ai appris pour ton père »

Tags: usage, prépositions, régionalismes

I ran into the above expression in Antonin Varenne's novel *Battues*, which also contains another example of similar usage of **pour**:

> [Le médecin] m'a dit pour les examens et pour [le commandant].

Evidently **pour** is synonymous to **au sujet de** in these sentences. However, I haven't found this type of usage documented in any dictionary.

[Gabriel Wyler's manual](http://gabrielwyler.com/zyy1491972517.html) is the only place where I found a few more examples of this usage along with the mention that it's a Swiss French expression. Antonin Varenne is a French author, however, and at least I didn't notice any other conspicuous regionalisms in his text.

Can it be deduced that this usage of **pour** is common at least in some parts of France? And what interests me most, would it be frowned upon by a speaker of standard Parisian French?

Comment: I have never set foot in Switzerland nor can I recall having even spoken French with anyone from Switzerland, but **j'ai appris pour [x]** is something I'd associate with "normal" French, even sophisticated French.

Comment: It is documented in dictionaries, e.g. [TLF C](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/pour) and commonly used in France.

Comment: It is commonly used by french Canadians as well.

Comment: Very common in France indeed.

Comment: @Laure Yes, I'm aware that **pour** in the sense "à propos de, au sujet de" is documented in TLF C but none of the examples given matches the pattern *verb* **pour** *qch*. But anyway, I'm glad to hear it's a common expression in France.

Comment: The really interesting thing is that 1) it is speech, not written French 2) It always  presupposes a context which the interlocutors either already know or have been discussing at some point. In that sense, it is a very interesting manner of expressing oneself. I might even go so far as to say it to some extent implies the speakers know each other somewhat well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is marked as spoken language. It is quite common. I would also argue that it's informal.**

Even if you take /pour/ to mean /au sujet de/, which it does here, there is something "left out". Putting in /au sujet de/ here for /J'ai appris au sujet de ton père/ is not even grammatical. And the /pour/ used like this is grammatical only in speech. And, /j'ai appris pour ton père/ is only grammatical in speech.

You would not see in a formal text: /L'institution a été informer pour les livres/. To mean: /L'institution a été informé que les livres seront livré par coursier/. In this example, **/pour/ stands in for the entire idea** of the books being delivered by messenger.

But, you might hear someone say that.

pour + noun or pronoun can stand for any number of contexts or co-texts that are not in the actual utterance.

In /Le médecin m'a dit pour les examens/, therefore one has to know what the context is. **Here, it's not**: **The doctor told me about the tests or exams**. **It's something like**: /The doctor told me that tests were being done or needed to be done or were done/.

Only a wider context will make it clear exactly.

With **apprendre**, here, for instance, it's /J'ai appris que votre père est mort ou est décédé [or apprendre la mort de ton]/ or something like that. Using the **pour** becomes a way to avoid having to say: /I was informed or learned of the death of your father/.

Contextually, the /pour/ + /noun or pronouns/ can replace an entire context or idea.

In English, /J'ai appris pour votre père/ would be: /About your father, I heard/. Or /I heard about your father/. The funny thing here is that  in English, /I heard about your father/ is completely standard both in speech and in writing, and the **spoken French aspect is lost** since there's not really any way to render it in the **marked sense of spoken language**.

[Kindly do not remove the slashes. I have re-edited myself for how I want the text to read. Thank you for your cooperation.]

Answer (score 0):

There's an idiom that uses *pour* in a similar way:

*Pour X, ça X.*

where the second X can be a superlative version of X. An example in English might be

*You wanna talk about rain, it's chucking it down right now.*